# Clicking navlinks navigates page to root (http://mypage.se/)

Tags: fullcalendar

When setting navLinks: true, fullcalendar makes anchor elements without a href property. That makes my page navigate to page root on click.

To resolve this issue tempraraly i have implemented this quick fix:

```
viewRender: function (view, element) {
                    var elements = $("[data-goto]");
                    elements.prop("href", "javascript:void(0)");
                }
```

Now i cant say for certain that this issue is related this project beeing a .net mvc project with knockout or the way browsers handle anchor clicks without href.

If anyone could shed some light on this for me it would be much appritiated.

I'm using FullCalendar v3.9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to Sammy.js not being set up correctly.

When clicking a link without a href tag sammy would redirect to root page automaticly.

Resolve by catching navigation to "/" and doing nothing.

```
Sammy(function () {
    this.get('/', function () {
    console.log("/");
    });
}).run();
```